# Django authenticate username not working with USERNAME_FIELD

Tags: django

I'm making a login for my app, with a custom user model and form, using an e-mail as username field in the model, and asking for email and password during the login process. The problem is that no matches are found in the authenticate method in my view, so I can't log in my users. Here is the code:

**user model**

```
class usuarios(AbstractBaseUser):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False)
    correo = models.EmailField(null=False, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'correo'
    objects = userManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.correo+' '+self.nombre+' '+self.apellido
```

**login form**

```
class loginForm(forms.Form):
    correo = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = usuarios
        fields = ("correo","password")
```

**login view**

```
class usuario_login(FormView):
    template_name = "user/usuario_login.html"
    form_class = loginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user:crear')
    def form_valid(self, form):
        usuario = authenticate(
            username=form.cleaned_data['correo'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
        )
        if usuario is not None:
            login(self.request, usuario)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                reverse_lazy('user:login')
            )
        return super(usuario_login, self).form_valid(form)
```

As you can see, in the login view I try to authenticate username (that's the email) and password before doing the login. I appreciate any help and then you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the problem was that as I changed the *AbstractBaseUser*, I had to change the authentication user model too, so I just added this in settings as the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) states:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.usuarios'
```